# Сохранить текст в БД вместе с переносами строк

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, как правильно записать в БД текст, чтобы при этом сохранились все переносы строк?
Текст парсится с сайта и потом уже пишется в БД.

Comment: а в чём сложность? перенос строки - такой же символ как буква `q` или цифра `5`. мускулю всё равно что вы там сохраняете.

Comment: Серверу всё равно, что записывать в БД, лишь бы соответствовало типу и размеру. Если перевод строки есть в текстовой переменной, то он и в поле записи таблицы попадёт - никуда не денется.

Comment: возможно, человек выдергивает текст со страницы, и убирает все тэги, поэтому у него и пропадают всяческие абзацы?

Comment: Пересмотрел код и понял, что это, видимо, потому, что я вытаскиваю инфу так:         $desc = $singleProduct->find('#tab-description')->text(), а не через ->html()

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Почему-то решил, что если сохранять теги, то они будут выводиться как текст)